# Stuck in proving a certain property

Tags: normed-spaces

I am proving that $\|f\| _{1} =\int_{a}^{b} |f|$ is a norm. but I am stuck in the second part of the first property.

**My attempt:**

Assume that $\|f\| _{1} = 0,$ then by the definition of $\|f\| _{1}$ and by Proposition 9 on pg.80 (Royden 4th edition), $|f| = 0$ **a.e.** on $[a,b].$ but then how this leads to that $f = 0.$ I was thinking about using $|f| = f^{+} + f^{-},$ but I do not know how.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Which space of functions are you working with?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos C[a,b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $|f(x_{0})|>0$ for some $x_{0}\in[a,b]$, then there are some $c>0$ and some closed interval $I\subseteq[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)|\geq c$ for $x\in I$, then $\|f\|_{1}\geq\displaystyle\int_{I}|f(x)|dx\geq\int_{I}cdx=c|I|>0$, so with $\|f\|_{1}=0$ it follows that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: I am sorry Proposition 9 on pg.80, said that $|f| = 0$ a.e. on $[a,b].$ then how this will lead to $f = 0$

Comment: My proof already explains to you. If you assume that there is one with $|f(x_{0})|>0$, you will get a contradiction.

Comment: So the proposition is wrong?

Comment: The proposition is absolutely correct, but I didn't use that, the above argument can prove the result you want directly.

Comment: " then there are some $c>0$ and some closed interval $I\subseteq[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)|\geq c$ for $x\in I$" Is this because of the continuity of $f$? I mean, if $f$ is continuous, then it is continuous in a small neighborhood?

Comment: That is due to continuity, you can run the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, choose $\epsilon=|f(x_{0})|/2$ and apply triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

For each $x\in[a,b]$, $\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert=0\iff f(x)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry Proposition 9 on pg.80, said that  $|f| = 0$ a.e. on $[a,b].$ then how this will lead to $f = 0$

Comment: A continuous function is $0$ a. e. if and only if it is $0$ everywhere.

Comment: why this is true? could you please explain this in details. is this because the continuity from left and right?

Comment: If $f(x)\neq0$ for some $x\in[a,b]$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall y\in[a,b]):\lvert y-x\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(y)-f(x)\bigr\rvert<\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert\implies f(y)\neq0.$$So, we have $f(y)\neq0$ in $[a,b]\cap(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, which is an interval with more than one point and so its Lebesgue measure is greater than $0$. In particular, it is *not* true that $f(x)=0$ a. e.

Comment: it is not clear for me why in the second line $f(y) \neq 0.$ could you clarify this please?

Comment: Sure. If $f(y)=0$, then $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert=\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert$. But we are assuming that $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert$

Comment: In your second comment, is this the definition of continuity that you are using? or what is  this property called?

Comment: It is the definition of continuity.

Comment: but where is the $\epsilon$?

Comment: The definition of continuity begins with “for every $\varepsilon>0$” and I took $\varepsilon=\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert$, which is greater than $0$, since $f(x)\neq0$.

Comment: In your second comment in the second line from below  is it $[a,b] \cap (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ instead? as you are using $\epsilon$ not $\delta$?

Comment: It was a mistake. It should have been $\delta$. Sorry about that.